# Filtering OneToMany-Relationships with CriteriaBuilder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, criteria, fetch

I'm trying to filter related Child-Entities with the CriteriaBuilder but don't get it. The Entities I have are:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @ManyToOne
    private Car car;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
   private Long value;
}

@Entity
public class Car {
    private Long id;
}
```

I would like to filter children depending on the value i.e. I don't want to get all children but those which value is in a list of values.

I tried it like this:

```
@Override
public List<Parent> loadParents(final long carId, final List<ParentType> types, final List<Long> values) {

    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    final CriteriaQuery<Parent> select = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Parent.class);

    final Root<Parent> from = select.from(Parent.class);

    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get("car").get("id"), carId));

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(types)) {
        predicates.add(from.get("type").in(types));
    }

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(values)) {
        final ListJoin<Parent, Child> join = from.join(em.getMetamodel().entity(Parent.class).getList("children", Child.class));
        final Predicate predicate = join.get(em.getMetamodel().entity(Child.class).getDeclaredSingularAttribute("value", Long.class)).in(values);
        predicates.add(predicate);
    }

    select.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

    final List<Parent> result = em.createQuery(select).getResultList();

    return result;
}
```

But I don't get the result I desired. Removing

```
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(values)) {
        final ListJoin<Parent, Child> join = from.join(em.getMetamodel().entity(Parent.class).getList("children", Child.class));
        final Predicate predicate = join.get(em.getMetamodel().entity(Child.class).getDeclaredSingularAttribute("value", Long.class)).in(values);
        predicates.add(predicate);
    }
```

I get parents with all their corresponding children. Can anybody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Here's what a query returning parents based on their children does: "Hey parents: who has a child named Bob?". And this query allows finding John. Then here's what getChildren() does: "Hello John. Who are your children?". And John will answer "Alice, Bob and Clara". Because these are Bob's children. If you want a subset of John's children, you need a query returning children. Not parents.

Comment: The analogy is too simple. Imagine this requirement: "retrieve all parents with the corresponding children visiting our school". To stay by your example, if bob visit the school I would get John -> bob and not John -> Alice, Bob, Clara. If bob does not visit the school I won't even get John. I need the parent with a children subset. I will indeed make 2 queries and the transform to a dto reflecting the relationship but to the subset. Ugly making multiple calls but nobody seems to know how to reflect this requirement in a criteria. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Whatever the query you make, the contract of `getChildren()` is to get the children of Bob, i.e. the members of the OneToMany association between parent and child. Not to get some of the children based on a previous query that happened to be executed. If you want some of the children, you need a query that selects children.

Comment: Yes, that's the way. Thank you.